# How to debug iOS app executed in mobile not launched by Xcode with connection USB cable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm working on Application, where I'm connecting External Device through USB female connector in iPad. Whereas I've connected external device, I can't connect my Data cable with Mac to debug the work. Anyone have idea, how can I debug without USB cable connected through Mac to iPad.
**Anyway to I can check previous logs of Device.**

Comment: If you find yourself frequently needing to debug outside of Xcode I would consider adding a framework such as Crashlytics to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Previous device logs are visible in devices tab, when selecting device, you'll see the device console.

If that's not enough, I suggest trying a logging framework such as [Antenna](https://github.com/mattt/Antenna).